# Excel 13 Issues with sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

Lines 200-195 wont sort alphabetically with the rest of the table. 0-195 I had no problems with but all of sudden these last chunks of info are just not allowed to be sorted. I can sort 200-195 within itself, but I can't have 194... let alone the rest of the sheet.

Comment: How do I provide a photo? This won't make much sense if no one can see what I'm talking about. It's my first time using this site.

Comment: So on line 194, there is a tiny blue corner piece in my O column. I thought it was like the green corners that show inconsistent formulas. But I can't interact with this bottom right blue corner. & its suspiciously in the row that begins my sorting issues.

Comment: The easiest way to get a screenshot of your issue is to resize Excel to the smallest necessary to show your problem, then press the Alt and PrintScreen keys together.  This will take a shot of just the Excel window into the clipboard, which you can then edit your question and paste the clip into the image upload box.

Comment: Upload your photo to imgur.com and edit your question to add the supplied link to your photo.  Someone will edit the link to make it appear in your question.

Comment: I think OP doesn't have enough rep to add a photo the usual way. The icon isn't even in the menu bar for her.  Biannca, if you do see an icon that's a square with a mountain it it, try @techturtle 's suggestion. Otherwise do the upload.

Comment: From excel forum.com: "The blue mark indicates the table is an "EXCEL TABLE" and not just a 'table' of data. The difference is that an Excel Table has special properties. They are used when you need to add additional rows of data to the table. The Excel table will copy any formatting and formulae automatically to any new rows to the table. If you don't add new rows to your Excel table, you can just turn it back to a normal table by right clicking, select Table and then "convert to range".  Suggest you try this.

Comment: Bandersnatch answered my question! It works perfectly now. Thank you all :)  I don't have the square icon with a mountain it it. But I'm sure I'll be on this site again, I'll gain nough rep with my noobness eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your data is in a table. Some of your data is outside of the table. Your sorts are only handling the data inside of the table.

1) Resize your table to capture all of your data
OR
2) Right click on the table, click on "Convert to range".